# Set of String with Stream to HashMap in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, set, java-stream

How do I create HashMap of String and List of String out of Set of String with Stream?

```
Set<String> mySet;
Map<String, List<String>> = mySet.stream().map(string -> {
   // string will be my key
   // I have here codes that return List<String>
   // what to return here?
}).collect(Collectors.toMap(.....)); // what codes needed here?
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need the `map()` step. The logic that produces a `List<String>` from a `String` should be passed to `Collectors.toMap()`:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = 
    mySet.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                   string -> {
                                       // put logic that returns List<String> here
                                   }));
```

Answer (score 1):

The `map` operation is useless here, because you don't want to change the string itself, or you would have to `map` it to an `Entry<String, List<String>>` and then collect them, but this is not easier.

Instead just build the map, the string as key and get your `codes` as values :

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = 
        mySet.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(str->str, str-> getCodesFromStr(str));
```

---

If you want to know, how it would be with a `map` operation and use `Entry` (a pair) :

```
Map<String, List<String>> = mySet.stream().map(str-> 
    new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String,List<String>>(str, getCodesFromStr(str))
).collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```